# image src link will show up on Bulma tile but my image.png won't show up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css, debugging, bulma

I've came across this weird error I'm getting where my image, which's in a folder in my directory, won't get recognized.  Upon debugging, in the `Network` tab I get the `Cannot GET /images/myImage.png` error.

However, if I put a random link from the web in the `src` attribute in `img`, then it works (the image appears).

Why's this happening and how can I fix it?

```
import React from 'react';

const Tiles = () => {
    return(
        <div className="tile">
            <div className="tile is-vertical is-8">
                <div className="tile">
                    <div className="tile is-parent is-vertical">
                        <article className="tile is-child notification">
                            <p className="title">Vertical...</p>
                            <p className="subtitle">Top tile</p>
                        </article>
                        <article className="tile is-child notification">
                            <p className="title">...tiles</p>
                            <p className="subtitle">Bottom tile</p>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                    <div className="tile is-parent">
                        <article className="tile is-child notification">
                            <p className="title">Middle tile</p>
                            <p className="subtitle">With an image</p>
                            <figure className="image is-4by3">
                                <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/640x480.png"/>
                            </figure>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="tile">
                    <article className="tile is-child notification">
                        <p className="title">Wide tile</p>
                        <p className="subtitle">Aligned with the right tile</p>
                        <div className="content">
                            {/* Here's the problem */}
                            <img src="../../images/myImage.png" alt="CPI pic"/>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="tile is-parent">
                <article className="tile is-child notification">
                    <div className="content">
                        <p className="title">Tall tile</p>
                        <p className="subtitle">With even more content</p>
                        <div className="content">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Tiles;
```

Answer (score 0):

Image src is not transfered where bundling your code.

When you specify external src like `https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/640x480.png` you have full url not dependant on your local file structure, which always will work.

In case of relative path like `../../images/myImage.png` it means that your application should looks 2 levels above for folder called images.
The source is not relative to your component file location. The src will be the same in your final js file where all your modules exists and will be `../../images/myImage.png` So it will relative to the current url not the file system.

To solve that you can for example use absolute path like `/app/images/myImage.png` depending on where your app is placed in the server.

If you are using webpack you can reqire your images relative to your component file like
`<img src={require('../../images/myImage.png')} />`
in such case your image file will be imported like a js module and depending on webpack configuration may be transfered to base64 string or not.

Comment: hmm ok, I'm using webpack and tried `{require('../../images/myImage.png')} />` but It still won't work for some reason